# Converting first letter of each word to uppercase

Tags: java

Does anyone know if there is another method other than `WordUtils.capitalize()` that converts the first letter of each word to upper case?

Comment: Use the `\b` symbol in a regular expression (using the java.util.regex library) to find a word boundary.

Comment: I was being direct I thought... Looking for a method other than one stated above that converts first letter of each word to a capital letter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use a method you create:

```
String CapsFirst(String str) {
    String[] words = str.split(" ");
    StringBuilder ret = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        ret.append(Character.toUpperCase(words[i].charAt(0)));
        ret.append(words[i].substring(1));
        if(i < words.length - 1) {
            ret.append(' ');
        }
    }
    return ret.toString();
}
```

Comment: I assume you mean "words[i]" inside the for-loop for the toUpperCase() and substring() methods.

Comment: @diveshpremdeep yep, whoops

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String caseFirst(String givenString) {
            String[] a= givenString.split(" ");
            StringBuffer s= new StringBuffer();
            for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            s.append(Character.toUpperCase(a[i].charAt(0))).append(a[i].substring(1)).append(" ");
            }          
          return s.toString().trim();
        }
```